# Parallel Coordinates plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, parallel-coordinates

Two and three dimensional data can be viewed relatively straight-forwardly using traditional plot types.  Even with four dimensional data, we can often find a way to display the data.  Dimensions above four, though, become increasingly difficult to display.  Fortunately, [parallel coordinates plots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates) provide a mechanism for viewing results with higher dimensions.

[image: Example Parallel Coordinates Plot from Wikipedia]

Several plotting packages provide parallel coordinates plots, such as [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/parallelcoords.html), [R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942508/implementation-of-parallel-coordinates), [VTK type 1](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/Infovis/ParallelCoordinatesView) and [VTK type 2](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Parallel-coordinates-Extraction-td4265045.html), but I don't see how to create one using Matplotlib.

1. Is there a built-in parallel coordinates plot in Matplotlib?  I certainly don't see one [in the gallery](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html).
2. If there is no built-in-type, is it possible to build a parallel coordinates plot using standard features of Matplotlib?

---

**Edit**:

Based on the answer provided by Zhenya below, I developed the following generalization that supports an arbitrary number of axes.  Following the plot style of the example I posted in the original question above, each axis gets its own scale.  I accomplished this by normalizing the data at each axis point and making the axes have a range of 0 to 1.  I then go back and apply labels to each tick-mark that give the correct value at that intercept.

The function works by accepting an iterable of data sets.  Each data set is considered a set of points where each point lies on a different axis.  The example in `__main__` grabs random numbers for each axis in two sets of 30 lines.  The lines are random within ranges that cause clustering of lines; a behavior I wanted to verify.

This solution isn't as good as a built-in solution since you have odd mouse behavior and I'm faking the data ranges through labels, but until Matplotlib adds a built-in solution, it's acceptable.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

def parallel_coordinates(data_sets, style=None):

    dims = len(data_sets[0])
    x    = range(dims)
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, dims-1, sharey=False)

    if style is None:
        style = ['r-']*len(data_sets)

    # Calculate the limits on the data
    min_max_range = list()
    for m in zip(*data_sets):
        mn = min(m)
        mx = max(m)
        if mn == mx:
            mn -= 0.5
            mx = mn + 1.
        r  = float(mx - mn)
        min_max_range.append((mn, mx, r))

    # Normalize the data sets
    norm_data_sets = list()
    for ds in data_sets:
        nds = [(value - min_max_range[dimension][0]) / 
                min_max_range[dimension][2] 
                for dimension,value in enumerate(ds)]
        norm_data_sets.append(nds)
    data_sets = norm_data_sets

    # Plot the datasets on all the subplots
    for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
        for dsi, d in enumerate(data_sets):
            ax.plot(x, d, style[dsi])
        ax.set_xlim([x[i], x[i+1]])

    # Set the x axis ticks 
    for dimension, (axx,xx) in enumerate(zip(axes, x[:-1])):
        axx.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator([xx]))
        ticks = len(axx.get_yticklabels())
        labels = list()
        step = min_max_range[dimension][2] / (ticks - 1)
        mn   = min_max_range[dimension][0]
        for i in xrange(ticks):
            v = mn + i*step
            labels.append('%4.2f' % v)
        axx.set_yticklabels(labels)


    # Move the final axis' ticks to the right-hand side
    axx = plt.twinx(axes[-1])
    dimension += 1
    axx.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator([x[-2], x[-1]]))
    ticks = len(axx.get_yticklabels())
    step = min_max_range[dimension][2] / (ticks - 1)
    mn   = min_max_range[dimension][0]
    labels = ['%4.2f' % (mn + i*step) for i in xrange(ticks)]
    axx.set_yticklabels(labels)

    # Stack the subplots 
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)

    return plt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import random
    base  = [0,   0,  5,   5,  0]
    scale = [1.5, 2., 1.0, 2., 2.]
    data = [[base[x] + random.uniform(0., 1.)*scale[x]
            for x in xrange(5)] for y in xrange(30)]
    colors = ['r'] * 30

    base  = [3,   6,  0,   1,  3]
    scale = [1.5, 2., 2.5, 2., 2.]
    data.extend([[base[x] + random.uniform(0., 1.)*scale[x]
                 for x in xrange(5)] for y in xrange(30)])
    colors.extend(['b'] * 30)

    parallel_coordinates(data, style=colors).show()
```

**Edit 2:**

Here is an example of what comes out of the above code when plotting [Fisher's Iris data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set).  It isn't quite as nice as the reference image from Wikipedia, but it is passable if all you have is Matplotlib and you need multi-dimensional plots.

[image: Example result of parallel coordinates plot from this answer]

Comment: +1 Excellent question! I'm sure that the answer to #2 is yes, but I don't know how easy or difficult it is.

Comment: getting the lines will be straightforward. Getting the axes may be more difficult.

Comment: Nice function. I tried it with my discrete data set, but the labels on the axes are floats on strange positions like in your plot, why is it like that?

Comment: Somebody did make a Python file with a nice interface for this: https://github.com/gregornickel/pcp

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm sure there is a better way of doing it, but here's a quick-and-dirty one (a really dirty one):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

#vectors to plot: 4D for this example
y1=[1,2.3,8.0,2.5]
y2=[1.5,1.7,2.2,2.9]

x=[1,2,3,8] # spines

fig,(ax,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey=False)

# plot the same on all the subplots
ax.plot(x,y1,'r-', x,y2,'b-')
ax2.plot(x,y1,'r-', x,y2,'b-')
ax3.plot(x,y1,'r-', x,y2,'b-')

# now zoom in each of the subplots 
ax.set_xlim([ x[0],x[1]])
ax2.set_xlim([ x[1],x[2]])
ax3.set_xlim([ x[2],x[3]])

# set the x axis ticks 
for axx,xx in zip([ax,ax2,ax3],x[:-1]):
  axx.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator([xx]))
ax3.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator([x[-2],x[-1]]))  # the last one

# EDIT: add the labels to the rightmost spine
for tick in ax3.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
  tick.label2On=True

# stack the subplots together
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)

plt.show()
```

This is essentially based on a (much nicer) one by Joe Kingon, [Python/Matplotlib - Is there a way to make a discontinuous axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656798/python-matplotlib-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-discontinuous-axis). You might also want to have a look at the other answer to the same question.

In this example I don't even attempt at scaling the vertical scales, since it depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

EDIT: Here is the result[image]

Comment: @Simon: yes, you need `dim-1` subplots

Comment: Nice approach.  On my display, the last axis doesn't have any units on it.  How would you add the units to the last axis?  I have two other questions, but they may go beyond the scope of this question. 1) Can you label the axis?  2) The 'move' tool on interactive plots allows each axis to be moved independent of the others.  Can you constrain them to all move together and only in the y-dimension?

Comment: @Nathan: I've edited the answer to add tick marks to the rightmost axis. There are various ways you can label the axes --- see e.g. this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236238/using-matplotlib-how-do-i-whiten-the-background-of-the-axis-label. With your second question, I've no idea, so if you make it a separate question, there's a chance somebody more knowledgeable will be able to see it.

Comment: @Zhenya This has been an awesome starting point!  I'm working on finishing up the fine details and will be posting the fully fleshed out solution in the next couple of days.  My hang up right now is dealing with the vertical axes.  To match the figure I cited in the question, each axis has to have an independent scale.  The sub-plot method, though, has an independent scale across *an entire sub-plot*.  To get axis-dependent scales, I've normalized the data on each axis and then applied custom labels to each axis.  I also need twinx for the last sub-plot so the last two axis are independent.

Answer (score 62):

[pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#parallel-coordinates) has a parallel coordinates wrapper:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import parallel_coordinates

data = pandas.read_csv(r'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pandas\tests\data\iris.csv', sep=',')
parallel_coordinates(data, 'Name')
plt.show()
```

[image: screenshot]

Source code, how they made it: [plotting.py#L494](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tools/plotting.py#L494)

Comment: Can each axis be scaled independently?  If I have mutliple axis with wildly different scales (say 0 to 1 and 0 to 1e6), uniform axis scaling results in unreadable plots.

Comment: Is there a way to turn it into an interactive tool?

Comment: Scaling each axis could be hacked by just dividing out some constant from your data and making note of the constant in the legend, for example.

Comment: @gradi3nt That doesn't really work in practice, though, because, at least in the image above, only one of the axes has units on it. You'd also need to somehow denote the units on the other axes to make scaling a practical solution.

Comment: `from pandas.tools.plotting import parallel_coordinates` is now deprecated, the deprecation warning recommends using `from pandas.plotting import parallel_coordinates` instead (still works exactly the same, though).

Answer (score 33):

When answering a related question, I worked out a version using only one subplot (so it can be easily fit together with other plots) and optionally using cubic bezier curves to connect the points. The plot adjusts itself to the desired number of axes.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np

fig, host = plt.subplots()

# create some dummy data
ynames = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5']
N1, N2, N3 = 10, 5, 8
N = N1 + N2 + N3
category = np.concatenate([np.full(N1, 1), np.full(N2, 2), np.full(N3, 3)])
y1 = np.random.uniform(0, 10, N) + 7 * category
y2 = np.sin(np.random.uniform(0, np.pi, N)) ** category
y3 = np.random.binomial(300, 1 - category / 10, N)
y4 = np.random.binomial(200, (category / 6) ** 1/3, N)
y5 = np.random.uniform(0, 800, N)

# organize the data
ys = np.dstack([y1, y2, y3, y4, y5])[0]
ymins = ys.min(axis=0)
ymaxs = ys.max(axis=0)
dys = ymaxs - ymins
ymins -= dys * 0.05  # add 5% padding below and above
ymaxs += dys * 0.05
dys = ymaxs - ymins

# transform all data to be compatible with the main axis
zs = np.zeros_like(ys)
zs[:, 0] = ys[:, 0]
zs[:, 1:] = (ys[:, 1:] - ymins[1:]) / dys[1:] * dys[0] + ymins[0]


axes = [host] + [host.twinx() for i in range(ys.shape[1] - 1)]
for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.set_ylim(ymins[i], ymaxs[i])
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
    if ax != host:
        ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
        ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')
        ax.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", i / (ys.shape[1] - 1)))

host.set_xlim(0, ys.shape[1] - 1)
host.set_xticks(range(ys.shape[1]))
host.set_xticklabels(ynames, fontsize=14)
host.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=7)
host.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
host.xaxis.tick_top()
host.set_title('Parallel Coordinates Plot', fontsize=18)

colors = plt.cm.tab10.colors
for j in range(N):
    # to just draw straight lines between the axes:
    # host.plot(range(ys.shape[1]), zs[j,:], c=colors[(category[j] - 1) % len(colors) ])

    # create bezier curves
    # for each axis, there will a control vertex at the point itself, one at 1/3rd towards the previous and one
    #   at one third towards the next axis; the first and last axis have one less control vertex
    # x-coordinate of the control vertices: at each integer (for the axes) and two inbetween
    # y-coordinate: repeat every point three times, except the first and last only twice
    verts = list(zip([x for x in np.linspace(0, len(ys) - 1, len(ys) * 3 - 2, endpoint=True)],
                     np.repeat(zs[j, :], 3)[1:-1]))
    # for x,y in verts: host.plot(x, y, 'go') # to show the control points of the beziers
    codes = [Path.MOVETO] + [Path.CURVE4 for _ in range(len(verts) - 1)]
    path = Path(verts, codes)
    patch = patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='none', lw=1, edgecolor=colors[category[j] - 1])
    host.add_patch(patch)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Here's similar code for the iris data set. The second axis is reversed to avoid some crossing lines.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
ynames = iris.feature_names
ys = iris.data
ymins = ys.min(axis=0)
ymaxs = ys.max(axis=0)
dys = ymaxs - ymins
ymins -= dys * 0.05  # add 5% padding below and above
ymaxs += dys * 0.05

ymaxs[1], ymins[1] = ymins[1], ymaxs[1]  # reverse axis 1 to have less crossings
dys = ymaxs - ymins

# transform all data to be compatible with the main axis
zs = np.zeros_like(ys)
zs[:, 0] = ys[:, 0]
zs[:, 1:] = (ys[:, 1:] - ymins[1:]) / dys[1:] * dys[0] + ymins[0]

fig, host = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))

axes = [host] + [host.twinx() for i in range(ys.shape[1] - 1)]
for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.set_ylim(ymins[i], ymaxs[i])
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
    if ax != host:
        ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
        ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')
        ax.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", i / (ys.shape[1] - 1)))

host.set_xlim(0, ys.shape[1] - 1)
host.set_xticks(range(ys.shape[1]))
host.set_xticklabels(ynames, fontsize=14)
host.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=7)
host.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
host.xaxis.tick_top()
host.set_title('Parallel Coordinates Plot — Iris', fontsize=18, pad=12)

colors = plt.cm.Set2.colors
legend_handles = [None for _ in iris.target_names]
for j in range(ys.shape[0]):
    # create bezier curves
    verts = list(zip([x for x in np.linspace(0, len(ys) - 1, len(ys) * 3 - 2, endpoint=True)],
                     np.repeat(zs[j, :], 3)[1:-1]))
    codes = [Path.MOVETO] + [Path.CURVE4 for _ in range(len(verts) - 1)]
    path = Path(verts, codes)
    patch = patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='none', lw=2, alpha=0.7, edgecolor=colors[iris.target[j]])
    legend_handles[iris.target[j]] = patch
    host.add_patch(patch)
host.legend(legend_handles, iris.target_names,
            loc='lower center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.18),
            ncol=len(iris.target_names), fancybox=True, shadow=True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: iris example]

The code can be adjusted as follows to use it as a function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np


def parallelCoordinatesPlot(title, N, data, category, ynames, colors=None, category_names=None):
    """
    A legend is added, if category_names is not None.

    :param title: The title of the plot.
    :param N: Number of data sets (i.e., lines).
    :param data: A list containing one array per parallel axis, each containing N data points.
    :param category: An array containing the category of each data set.
    :param category_names: Labels of the categories. Must have the same length as set(category).
    :param ynames: The labels of the parallel axes.
    :param colors: A colormap to use.
    :return:
    """

    fig, host = plt.subplots()

    # organize the data
    ys = np.dstack(data)[0]
    ymins = ys.min(axis=0)
    ymaxs = ys.max(axis=0)
    dys = ymaxs - ymins
    ymins -= dys * 0.05  # add 5% padding below and above
    ymaxs += dys * 0.05
    dys = ymaxs - ymins

    # transform all data to be compatible with the main axis
    zs = np.zeros_like(ys)
    zs[:, 0] = ys[:, 0]
    zs[:, 1:] = (ys[:, 1:] - ymins[1:]) / dys[1:] * dys[0] + ymins[0]

    axes = [host] + [host.twinx() for i in range(ys.shape[1] - 1)]
    for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
        ax.set_ylim(ymins[i], ymaxs[i])
        ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
        ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
        if ax != host:
            ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
            ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')
            ax.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", i / (ys.shape[1] - 1)))

    host.set_xlim(0, ys.shape[1] - 1)
    host.set_xticks(range(ys.shape[1]))
    host.set_xticklabels(ynames, fontsize=14)
    host.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=7)
    host.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    host.xaxis.tick_top()
    host.set_title(title, fontsize=18)

    if colors is None:
        colors = plt.cm.tab10.colors
    if category_names is not None:
        legend_handles = [None for _ in category_names]
    else:
        legend_handles = [None for _ in set(category)]
    for j in range(N):
        # to just draw straight lines between the axes:
        # host.plot(range(ys.shape[1]), zs[j,:], c=colors[(category[j] - 1) % len(colors) ])

        # create bezier curves
        # for each axis, there will a control vertex at the point itself, one at 1/3rd towards the previous and one
        #   at one third towards the next axis; the first and last axis have one less control vertex
        # x-coordinate of the control vertices: at each integer (for the axes) and two inbetween
        # y-coordinate: repeat every point three times, except the first and last only twice
        verts = list(zip([x for x in np.linspace(0, len(ys) - 1, len(ys) * 3 - 2, endpoint=True)],
                         np.repeat(zs[j, :], 3)[1:-1]))
        # for x,y in verts: host.plot(x, y, 'go') # to show the control points of the beziers
        codes = [Path.MOVETO] + [Path.CURVE4 for _ in range(len(verts) - 1)]
        path = Path(verts, codes)
        patch = patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='none', lw=1, edgecolor=colors[category[j] - 1])
        legend_handles[category[j] - 1] = patch
        host.add_patch(patch)

        if category_names is not None:
            host.legend(legend_handles, category_names,
                        loc='lower center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.18),
                        ncol=len(category_names), fancybox=True, shadow=True)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    ynames = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5']
    N1, N2, N3 = 10, 5, 8
    N = N1 + N2 + N3
    category = np.concatenate([np.full(N1, 1), np.full(N2, 2), np.full(N3, 3)])
    y1 = np.random.uniform(0, 10, N) + 7 * category
    y2 = np.sin(np.random.uniform(0, np.pi, N)) ** category
    y3 = np.random.binomial(300, 1 - category / 10, N)
    y4 = np.random.binomial(200, (category / 6) ** 1 / 3, N)
    y5 = np.random.uniform(0, 800, N)

    parallelCoordinatesPlot(ynames=ynames, data=[y1, y2, y3, y4, y5], category=category, N=N,
                            title='Parallel Coordinates Plot without Legend')

    parallelCoordinatesPlot(ynames=ynames, data=[y1, y2, y3, y4, y5], category=category, N=N,
                            title='Parallel Coordinates Plot with Legend', category_names=['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3'])
```

Comment: This looks great! All it needs is a function interface to make it easier to work with.

Answer (score 13):

When using pandas (like suggested by theta), there is no way to scale the axes independently.

> The reason you can't find the different vertical axes is because there aren't any. Our parallel coordinates is "faking" the other two axes by just drawing a vertical line and some labels.

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7083#issuecomment-74253671

Answer (score 5):

I've adapted the @JohanC code to a pandas dataframe and expanded it to also work with categorical variables. The code needs more improving, like being able to put also a numerical variable as the first one in the dataframe, but I think it is nice for now.

```
# Paths:
path_data = "data/"

# Packages:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from functools import reduce

# Display options:
pd.set_option("display.width", 1200)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 300)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 300)

# Dataset:
df = pd.read_csv(path_data + "nasa_exoplanets.csv")
df_varnames = pd.read_csv(path_data + "nasa_exoplanets_var_names.csv")

# Variables (the first variable must be categoric):
my_vars = ["discoverymethod", "pl_orbper", "st_teff", "disc_locale", "sy_gaiamag"]
my_vars_names = reduce(pd.DataFrame.append,
                       map(lambda i: df_varnames[df_varnames["var"] == i], my_vars))
my_vars_names = my_vars_names["var_name"].values.tolist()

# Adapt the data:
df = df.loc[df["pl_letter"] == "d"]
df_plot = df[my_vars]
df_plot = df_plot.dropna()
df_plot = df_plot.reset_index(drop = True)

# Convert to numeric matrix:
ym = []
dics_vars = []
for v, var in enumerate(my_vars):
    if df_plot[var].dtype.kind not in ["i", "u", "f"]:
        dic_var = dict([(val, c) for c, val in enumerate(df_plot[var].unique())])
        dics_vars += [dic_var]
        ym += [[dic_var[i] for i in df_plot[var].tolist()]]
    else:
        ym += [df_plot[var].tolist()]
ym = np.array(ym).T

# Padding:
ymins = ym.min(axis = 0)
ymaxs = ym.max(axis = 0)
dys = ymaxs - ymins
ymins -= dys*0.05
ymaxs += dys*0.05

# Reverse some axes for better visual:
axes_to_reverse = [0, 1]
for a in axes_to_reverse:
    ymaxs[a], ymins[a] = ymins[a], ymaxs[a]
dys = ymaxs - ymins

# Adjust to the main axis:
zs = np.zeros_like(ym)
zs[:, 0] = ym[:, 0]
zs[:, 1:] = (ym[:, 1:] - ymins[1:])/dys[1:]*dys[0] + ymins[0]

# Colors:
n_levels = len(dics_vars[0])
my_colors = ["#F41E1E", "#F4951E", "#F4F01E", "#4EF41E", "#1EF4DC", "#1E3CF4", "#F41EF3"]
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("my_palette", my_colors)
my_palette = [cmap(i/n_levels) for i in np.array(range(n_levels))]

# Plot:
fig, host_ax = plt.subplots(
    figsize = (20, 10),
    tight_layout = True
)

# Make the axes:
axes = [host_ax] + [host_ax.twinx() for i in range(ym.shape[1] - 1)]
dic_count = 0
for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.set_ylim(
        bottom = ymins[i],
        top = ymaxs[i]
    )
    ax.spines.top.set_visible(False)
    ax.spines.bottom.set_visible(False)
    ax.ticklabel_format(style = 'plain')
    if ax != host_ax:
        ax.spines.left.set_visible(False)
        ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position("right")
        ax.spines.right.set_position(
            (
                "axes",
                 i/(ym.shape[1] - 1)
             )
        )
    if df_plot.iloc[:, i].dtype.kind not in ["i", "u", "f"]:
        dic_var_i = dics_vars[dic_count]
        ax.set_yticks(
            range(len(dic_var_i))
        )
        ax.set_yticklabels(
            [key_val for key_val in dics_vars[dic_count].keys()]
        )
        dic_count += 1
host_ax.set_xlim(
    left = 0,
    right = ym.shape[1] - 1
)
host_ax.set_xticks(
    range(ym.shape[1])
)
host_ax.set_xticklabels(
    my_vars_names,
    fontsize = 14
)
host_ax.tick_params(
    axis = "x",
    which = "major",
    pad = 7
)

# Make the curves:
host_ax.spines.right.set_visible(False)
host_ax.xaxis.tick_top()
for j in range(ym.shape[0]):
    verts = list(zip([x for x in np.linspace(0, len(ym) - 1, len(ym)*3 - 2, 
                                             endpoint = True)],
                 np.repeat(zs[j, :], 3)[1: -1]))
    codes = [Path.MOVETO] + [Path.CURVE4 for _ in range(len(verts) - 1)]
    path = Path(verts, codes)
    color_first_cat_var = my_palette[dics_vars[0][df_plot.iloc[j, 0]]]
    patch = patches.PathPatch(
        path,
        facecolor = "none",
        lw = 2,
        alpha = 0.7,
        edgecolor = color_first_cat_var
    )
    host_ax.add_patch(patch)
```

[image: Parallel sets in matplotlib with numerical and categorical data]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

plotly has a nice interactive solution called [parallel_coordinates](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.parallel_coordinates.html) which works just fine:

```py
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.parallel_coordinates(df, color="species_id", labels={"species_id": "Species",
                "sepal_width": "Sepal Width", "sepal_length": "Sepal Length",
                "petal_width": "Petal Width", "petal_length": "Petal Length", },
                             color_continuous_scale=px.colors.diverging.Tealrose,
                             color_continuous_midpoint=2)
fig.show()
```

[image: parallel_coordinates]

Answer (score 4):

I want to plug a beta-released parallel coordinate plotting package called [Paxplot](https://kravitsjacob.github.io/paxplot/index.html) which is based on Matplotlib. It uses similar underlying logic to the other answers and extends functionality while maintaining clean usage.

The documentation provides examples of [basic usage](https://kravitsjacob.github.io/paxplot/getting_started.html), [advanced usage](https://kravitsjacob.github.io/paxplot/advanced_usage.html), and [usage with Pandas](https://kravitsjacob.github.io/paxplot/pandas_usage.html). As per the figure provided in the original question, I have provided a solution that plots the [iris](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html) dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import paxplot

# Import data
iris = load_iris(as_frame=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
    columns=iris['feature_names'] + ['target']
)
cols = df.columns

# Create figure
paxfig = paxplot.pax_parallel(n_axes=len(cols))
paxfig.plot(df.to_numpy())

# Add labels
paxfig.set_labels(cols)

# Set ticks
paxfig.set_ticks(
    ax_idx=-1,
    ticks=[0, 1, 2],
    labels=iris.target_names
)

# Add colorbar
color_col = 0
paxfig.add_colorbar(
    ax_idx=color_col,
    cmap='viridis',
    colorbar_kwargs={'label': cols[color_col]}
)

plt.show()
```

[image: Iris Plot]

For full disclosure, I created Paxplot and have been developing and maintaining it with some friends. Definitely feel free to reach out if you are interested in contributing!

Answer (score 1):

- This is a version using `TensorBoard`, if not strictly need matplotlib figure.
- I'm looking around for something works like [Visualize the results in TensorBoard's HParams plugin](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/hyperparameter_tuning_with_hparams#4_visualize_the_results_in_tensorboards_hparams_plugin) result. Here is a wrapped function just plotting ignoring training in that tutorial, using TensorBoard. The logic is using `metrics_name` specified key as metrics, using other columns as `HParams`. For any other detail, refer original tutorial.

```py
import os
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorboard.plugins.hparams import api as hp

def tensorboard_parallel_coordinates_plot(dataframe, metrics_name, metrics_display_name=None, skip_columns=[], log_dir='logs/hparam_tuning'):
    skip_columns = skip_columns + [metrics_name]
    to_hp_discrete = lambda column: hp.HParam(column, hp.Discrete(np.unique(dataframe[column].values).tolist()))
    hp_params_dict = {column: to_hp_discrete(column) for column in dataframe.columns if column not in skip_columns}

    if dataframe[metrics_name].values.dtype == 'object': # Not numeric
        metrics_map = {ii: id for id, ii in enumerate(np.unique(dataframe[metrics_name]))}
        description = json.dumps(metrics_map)
    else:
        metrics_map, description = None, None

    METRICS = metrics_name if metrics_display_name is None else metrics_display_name
    with tf.summary.create_file_writer(log_dir).as_default():
        metrics = [hp.Metric(METRICS, display_name=METRICS, description=description)]
        hp.hparams_config(hparams=list(hp_params_dict.values()), metrics=metrics)

    for id in dataframe.index:
        log = dataframe.iloc[id]
        hparams = {hp_unit: log[column] for column, hp_unit in hp_params_dict.items()}
        print({hp_unit.name: hparams[hp_unit] for hp_unit in hparams})
        run_dir = os.path.join(log_dir, 'run-%d' % id)
        with tf.summary.create_file_writer(run_dir).as_default():
            hp.hparams(hparams)  # record the values used in this trial
            metric_item = log[metrics_name] if metrics_map is None else metrics_map[log[metrics_name]]
            tf.summary.scalar(METRICS, metric_item, step=1)

    print()
    if metrics_map is not None:
        print("metrics_map:", metrics_map)
    print("Start tensorboard by: tensorboard --logdir {}".format(log_dir))
```

**Plotting test**:

```py
aa = pd.read_csv('https://raw.github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/main/pandas/tests/io/data/csv/iris.csv')
tensorboard_parallel_coordinates_plot(aa, metrics_name="Name", log_dir="logs/iris")
# metrics_map: {'Iris-setosa': 0, 'Iris-versicolor': 1, 'Iris-virginica': 2}
# Start tensorboard by: tensorboard --logdir logs/iris

!tensorboard --logdir logs/iris
# TensorBoard 2.8.0 at http://localhost:6006/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Open tesnorboard link, default `http://localhost:6006/`, go to `HPARAMS` -> `PARALLEL COORDINATES VIEW` will show the result:
[image: tensorboard_iris]

- TensorBoard result is interactive. But this is designed for plotting model hyper parameters tuning results, so I think it's not friendly for plotting large dataset.
- You have to clean saved data manually if plotting new data in same `log_dir` directory.
- It seems the final metrics item has to be numeric, while other axes don't have to.

```py
fake_data = {
    "optimizer": ["sgd", "adam", "adam", "lamb", "lamb", "lamb", "lamb"],
    "weight_decay": [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3],
    "rescale_mode": ["tf", "tf", "tf", "tf", "tf", "torch", "torch"],
    "accuracy": [78.5, 78.2, 78.8, 79.2, 79.3, 79.5, 79.6],
}

aa = pd.DataFrame(fake_data)
tensorboard_parallel_coordinates_plot(aa, "accuracy", log_dir="logs/fake")
# Start tensorboard by: tensorboard --logdir logs/fake

!tensorboard --logdir logs/fake
# TensorBoard 2.8.0 at http://localhost:6006/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

[image: tensorboard_fake]

Answer (score 0):

Best example I've seen thus far is this one

https://python.g-node.org/python-summerschool-2013/_media/wiki/datavis/olympics_vis.py

See the normalised_coordinates function. Not super fast, but works from what I've tried.

```
normalised_coordinates(['VAL_1', 'VAL_2', 'VAL_3'], np.array([[1230.23, 1500000, 12453.03], [930.23, 140000, 12453.03], [130.23, 120000, 1243.03]]), [1, 2, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Still far from perfect but it works and is relatively short:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_parallel(data,labels):

    data=np.array(data)
    x=list(range(len(data[0])))
    fig, axis = plt.subplots(1, len(data[0])-1, sharey=False)


    for d in data:
        for i, a in enumerate(axis):
            temp=d[i:i+2].copy()
            temp[1]=(temp[1]-np.min(data[:,i+1]))*(np.max(data[:,i])-np.min(data[:,i]))/(np.max(data[:,i+1])-np.min(data[:,i+1]))+np.min(data[:,i])
            a.plot(x[i:i+2], temp)


    for i, a in enumerate(axis):
        a.set_xlim([x[i], x[i+1]])
        a.set_xticks([x[i], x[i+1]])
        a.set_xticklabels([labels[i], labels[i+1]], minor=False, rotation=45)
        a.set_ylim([np.min(data[:,i]),np.max(data[:,i])])


    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)

    plt.show()
```