# Matplotlib: Can a plot a line from one set of axes to another?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I wish to plot marker "x" at say [100,100] and then plot "o" at [20%, 30%] (different axes, same plot) and connect them with a line. I can do something similar on the same axes (with the same units) with one call to plot the line, another call to plot the "x" and a final call to plot the "o".

```
ax.plot(x,y,"-")
ax.scatter(x[0], y[0], marker='x')
ax.scatter(x[1], y[1], marker='o')
```

However, how can I get the line to go from one set of axes to the other?

Comment: You should include some more code, as it is rather hard to understand exactly what you mean. Without some more context we may only guess how you have created your axes.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `annotate` to draw single lines:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax2 = plt.subplot(122)

x = [[1, 2], [3,4]]
y = [[5, 6], [6,4]]

ax1.scatter(x[0], y[0])
ax2.scatter(x[1], y[1])


ax1.annotate('', xy=(x[0][0], y[0][0]), xytext=(x[1][0], y[1][0]), xycoords=ax1.transData, 
         textcoords=ax2.transData, 
         arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', arrowstyle='-',, clip_on=False))
ax2.annotate('', xy=(x[0][0], y[0][0]), xytext=(x[1][0], y[1][0]), xycoords=ax1.transData, 
         textcoords=ax2.transData, 
         arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', arrowstyle='-'))
```

which produces this result:

[image: matplotlib plot]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question completely, but put this together to see if it is what you were looking for?

```
import pylab

#generate array of data for example
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(1,250,1)
y = np.arange(1,250,1)

#find marker for your 'x' points
x_marker_location = 100
x_marker_x = x[np.where(x==x_marker_location)]  # np.where looks for location in your data where array equals a value. Alternatively, x_marker_x and y would just be a coordinate value.
x_marker_y = y[np.where(y==x_marker_location)]

#create scaling factors
o_marker_scale_x = 0.2
o_marker_scale_y = 0.3
#find marker for your 'o' points
o_marker_x = x[np.where(x==x_marker_location*o_marker_scale_x)]
o_marker_y = y[np.where(y==x_marker_location*o_marker_scale_y)]

#draw line of all data
pylab.plot(x,y,"-",color='black')
#draw points interested in
pylab.scatter(x_marker_x, x_marker_y, marker='x')
pylab.scatter(o_marker_x, o_marker_y, marker='o')
#draw connecting line - answer to question?
pylab.plot([x_marker_x,o_marker_x],[x_marker_y,o_marker_y],'-',color='red')

#show plot
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who arrived at this looking to plot high-dimensional data on one figure, by drawing lines connecting points in the different dimensions, note that what you are looking for is called a "Parallel Coordinates Plot".

There are possible solutions in matplotlib, as well as solutions using pandas and plotly:

[Parallel Coordinates plot in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230638/parallel-coordinates-plot-in-matplotlib)