# Matplotlib arbitrary line over multi axes plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a six-axes matplotlib figure, and i would like to draw a simple horizontal red line for x=2 over the whole figure. Is that possible ?

I saw this : [Matplotlib: Can a plot a line from one set of axes to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571474/matplotlib-can-a-plot-a-line-from-one-set-of-axes-to-another) which is promising, but a bit complex - is there another simpler way ?

```
fig , axes = plt.subplots(1,6)
iteration  = -1

for label, group in  X.groupby(["quantile_Y"])["FTE"]:
    iteration       +=1
    to_draw          = axes[iteration]
    local_title      = "Y < "+label[label.find(",")+2:-5]
    group.plot(kind  = "box"         ,  
               ax    = to_draw       , 
               ylim  = (0,5)         ,  
               title = local_title   )

    to_draw.label_outer()
    to_draw.set_axis_bgcolor("white")
    to_draw.plot([0,0], [10,10])
plt.show()`
```

Which gives me :

[image]

It is clear that a straight line at x=2 could be useful ;)

Comment: why are you plotting on separate axes?

Comment: I don't know... can we plot on the same one ?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery.html#statistics and http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/grouped_boxplot.html

Comment: and here's a questions about horizontal lines and subplots, found by searching the matplotlib tag for "horizontal line" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129007/plotting-a-horizontal-line-on-multiple-subplots-in-python-using-pyplot

Comment: ... Well I had a look at http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/examples/statistics/boxplot_demo.html and I still see they use several axes. As for http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/grouped_boxplot.html It doesn't really fit my need I think.

Comment: The same : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129007/plotting-a-horizontal-line-on-multiple-subplots-in-python-using-pyplot doesn't answer needer the question I think, as it is plotting an horizontal by axis, and not one through different axis

Comment: And upon further inspection, I'm sure you'll notice that each of the examples has multiple boxes on each of the individual axes objects.

Comment: I don't know, if I see : 
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3, figsize=(6, 6), sharey=True)
axes[0, 0].boxplot(data, labels=labels)
axes[0, 0].set_title('Default', fontsize=fs)

axes[0, 1].boxplot(data, labels=labels, showmeans=True)
axes[0, 1].set_title('showmeans=True', fontsize=fs) 

To me this is like two axes

Comment: two axes, each with multiple boxes -- are you looking at the images?

Comment: ... you may be right...

Comment: How would you prepare the data  to do the whole in one row ? Have to make a dataframe with one column by subset, and a line by quantile ?

Comment: list of 1-D arrays

Comment: `X.groupby` implies you have dataframe: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#box-plots