# Trying to visualize a sorted table with matplotlib (parallel coordinates?)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to visualize a sorted table (sorted on a column). My ideal result should be something like

[visualization of a sorted table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTCKc.jpg)

Any suggestion on how to reach this goal with matplotlib?

I'have already tried with suggestions given [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#parallel-coordinates) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230638/parallel-coordinates-plot-in-matplotlib) but I'm looking for something fancier like that in the attached image.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I don't think matplotlib supports this kind of plots.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I answered your question, even though it doesn't really comply with the standards of SO: SO is not a coding service, so usually you will not get answers unless you show what you have tried yourself (yes, post your code) and where you failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib does not support this directly, but it is fairly easy to replicate the plot that you have linked to.

The function below does something similar given a 2d array of data. It can be sorted or not, the function doesn't really care.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy as np

def sorted_table_plot(data, labels, categories, cmap=None, ax=None):

    # check if an axes was supplied
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    # check if a colormap was supplied
    if cmap is None:
        cmap = plt.cm.jet

    # generate the grid arrays with the coordinates for the annotations
    yy, xx = np.mgrid[:data.shape[0], :data.shape[1]]
    x = xx.flatten()
    y = yy.flatten()
    d = data.flatten()

    # a norm object which we will use with the colorbar
    norm = plt.Normalize(d.min(), d.max())

    # iterate over the data points and draw the labels
    for di, xi, yi in zip(d, x, y):
        color = cmap(norm(di))
        hsv = mcolors.rgb_to_hsv(color[:3])
        fc = 'w' if hsv[2] < 0.7 else 'k'
        ax.annotate(str(di), xy=(xi,yi), xycoords="data",
                va="center", ha="center", color=fc,
                bbox=dict(boxstyle="circle", fc=color))

    # iteratve over all the appearing values and draw the lines
    for i in np.unique(data):
        xi, yi = x[d==i], y[d==i]
        idx = np.argsort(xi)
        plt.plot(xi[idx], yi[idx], color=plt.cm.jet(norm(i)), lw=2)

    # add the axes labels
    ax.set_xticks(xx[0,:])
    ax.set_xticklabels(categories)
    ax.set_yticks(yy[:,0])
    ax.set_yticklabels(labels)

    # adjust the axes ranges
    ax.set_xlim(xx[0,0] - 0.5, xx[-1,-1] + 0.5)
    ax.set_ylim(yy[-1,-1] + 0.5, yy[0,0] - 0.5)
```

Now, you can simply call it on a data array. In the following I created a random array, since you didn't care to supply an example data set.

```
# fix the seed for reproducability
np.random.seed(2)

# create random data
data = np.tile(np.arange(1,8), (3,1)).T
labels = map(lambda x: 'label ' + str(x), data[:,1])
categories = map(lambda x: 'cat ' + str(x), np.arange(data.shape[1])+1)
for i in range(1,data.shape[1]):
    # shuffle all but the first column
    np.random.shuffle(data[:,i])

# call the function and show the plot
sorted_table_plot(data, labels, categories)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]