# Pandas: parallel plots using groupie

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I was wondering if anyone could help me with parallel coordinate plotting.

First this is how the data looks like:

[image: Data] It's data manipulated from : https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Transportation/2016-Yellow-Taxi-Trip-Data/k67s-dv2t

So I'm trying to normalise some features and use that to compute the mean of trip distance, passenger count and payment amount for each day of the week.

```
from pandas.tools.plotting import parallel_coordinates

feature = ['trip_distance','passenger_count','payment_amount']

#normalizing data
for feature in features:
     df[feature] = (df[feature]-df[feature].min())/(df[feature].max()-df[feature].min())

#change format to datetime
pickup_time = pd.to_datetime(df['pickup_datetime'], format ='%d/%m/%y %H:%M')
#fill dayofweek column with 0~6 0:Monday and 6:Sunday
df['dayofweek'] = pickup_time.dt.weekday

mean_trip = df.groupby('dayofweek').trip_distance.mean()
mean_passanger = df.groupby('dayofweek').passenger_count.mean()
mean_payment = df.groupby('dayofweek').payment_amount.mean()

#parallel_coordinates('notsurewattoput')
```

So if I print mean_trip:

[image]

It shows the mean of each day of the week but I'm not sure how I would use this to draw a parallel coordinate plot with all 3 means on the same plot.

Does anyone know how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can change 3 times aggregating mean to one with output `DataFrame` instead 3 Series:

```
mean_trip = df.groupby('dayofweek').trip_distance.mean()
mean_passanger = df.groupby('dayofweek').passenger_count.mean()
mean_payment = df.groupby('dayofweek').payment_amount.mean()
```

to:

```
from pandas.tools.plotting import parallel_coordinates

cols = ['trip_distance','passenger_count','payment_amount']
df1 = df.groupby('dayofweek', as_index=False)[cols].mean()
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/45082022
parallel_coordinates(df1, class_column='dayofweek', cols=cols)
```

Comment: Thank you so much again! worked like magic ! DIdn't know you could combine that like that. Thank you !

Comment: just one question what does as_index = False do ?

Comment: It create column from `dayofweek`, it same working like `df.groupby('dayofweek')[cols].mean().reset_index()`