# pandas parallel plot with different axis ranges

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I have to plot a parallel plot of some dataset with varying ranges. When I googled I found one beautiful javascript example in [this website](http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/raw/3150059/).

I have creates some sample dataset for the test and would like to achieve parallel plot having **yxis-ticks** and **different-range yaxes** something similar to this image:
[image]

So far I have done this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import parallel_coordinates
np.random.seed(100)

%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame({'calcium': np.random.randint(0,7,5),
                  'calories': np.random.randint(200,900,5),
                 'fiber': np.random.randint(10,75,5),
                'potassium': np.random.randint(0,20,5)
                  })
df = df.T
df['name'] = df.index

df.reset_index(drop=True)

parallel_coordinates(df,'name')
```

The output is this:

[image]

As we can see the bottom curves are highly undiscernable. I would like to fix that.
I have googled and tried to find how to change the vertical y-axis tick marks and change ranges (normalize).

Help will be appreciated.
This is a beautiful plot, kudos to those who on the planet earth succeed to visualize this beautiful plot in python!!

Related links:
http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/raw/3150059/
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.plotting.parallel_coordinates.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html
[How to plot parallel coordinates on pandas DataFrame with some columns containing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44703994/how-to-plot-parallel-coordinates-on-pandas-dataframe-with-some-columns-containin)

**Update**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import parallel_coordinates
np.random.seed(100)

plt.style.use('ggplot')
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame({'calcium': np.random.randint(0,7,5),
                   'calories': np.random.randint(200,900,5),
                   'fiber': np.random.randint(10,75,5),
                   'potassium': np.random.randint(0,20,5),
                   'name': ['apple','banana','orange','mango','watermelon']

                  })
ax = parallel_coordinates(df,'name')
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

[image]

Still Cannot put ytick marks on middle axes.

Comment: Have you thought about using a logarithmic y axis? It is useful when the range of values is too wide to plot it in a linear axis.

Comment: Yes, that would widen the first y-axis ticklabels, but will have do more to give yticks for all other axes. My aim is to get plot like from blocks.org

Comment: But you are plotting all your elements in a single plot, they use multiple subplots. Are you asking for how to plot multiple plots with different y axis range?

Comment: Maybe my wording are different, please see that first image in the question, whatever the method they applied to get that beautiful picture, I am trying to get the figure like them. Also `ax.set_yscale('log')` was a good idea. Appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplot.html) on how to create multiple subplots (one for each element with different yaxis ranges). This is how you could make the figure you want.

Comment: I do not want to be a grumbler, but the plot you show as example is overloaded an not very useful imho. Just because it looks cool, doesnt mean that it is an informative plot.

Comment: I suppose beauty is in the eye of the beholder. That plot is incredibly busy, hard to interpret, and carries a lot of unintended implications. Line plots carry implicit notions about the continuity of the independent variable. *DO* calories come after calcium? Alphabetically, sure. In any other meaningful way? Not really. Why should it come after calcium? Plots should be *as simple as possible* to convey the information you're trying to convey

Comment: @PMende Agreed. Here I am learning to code and learning technicalities, aesthetics vs usefulness are another topic to discuss.

Answer (score 1):

This is *a* solution that will help improve readability using a broken y axes. I stole most of this code from [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(100)

%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame({'calcium': np.random.randint(0,7,5),
              'calories': np.random.randint(200,900,5),
             'fiber': np.random.randint(10,75,5),
            'potassium': np.random.randint(0,20,5)
              })

f, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)

#plot the same data on both axes
ax.plot(df)
ax2.plot(df)

# zoom-in / limit the view to different portions of the data
ax.set_ylim(250, 800)  # outliers only
ax2.set_ylim(0, 75)  # most of the data

# hide the spines between ax and ax2
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.xaxis.tick_top()
ax.tick_params(labeltop='off')  # don't put tick labels at the top
ax2.xaxis.tick_bottom()

d = .015  # how big to make the diagonal lines in axes coordinates
kwargs = dict(transform=ax.transAxes, color='k', clip_on=False)
ax.plot((-d, +d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)        # top-left diagonal
ax.plot((1 - d, 1 + d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)  # top-right diagonal

kwargs.update(transform=ax2.transAxes)  # switch to the bottom axes
ax2.plot((-d, +d), (1 - d, 1 + d), **kwargs)  # bottom-left diagonal
ax2.plot((1 - d, 1 + d), (1 - d, 1 + d), **kwargs)  # bottom-right diagonal


f.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=1.6, 
              bottom=0.1, top = 0.9, 
              hspace=0.3) # space between the two sections
f.legend(df.columns)

plt.show()
```

Which produces a plot that looks like this:
[image]

I still think that the calcium line is challenging to interpret but you could blow up the image or break the y axis again if the graph is simple enough to break into chunks.

Comment: `f.legend(labels=df.columns)  TypeError: legend() missing 1 required positional argument: 'handles'`

Comment: I'm on matplotlib 2.2.2, you could hack around by replacing  ax.plot(df) with 
    for col in df.columns:
        ax.plot(df[col], label=col) and replace f.legend(df.columns) with f.legend()