# Is it possible to create multiple axis plot side by side and have them connected?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data with 5 parameters, which I want to plot on multiple y axes and have them connected. Please see the example picture.

Currently I tried with normalizing all the values and create dictionary to do a scatter plot where on x axis would be values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and on y axis 5 parameter values for each data point. But this way I will need to add axis lines and values later on in Photoshop.

Is there a better way to create such graph using matplotlib and python?

[image: Example of desired plot]

Comment: such a graph is called "parallel coordinates plot". You find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230638/parallel-coordinates-plot-in-matplotlib. I also suggest to look at the plotting library plotly which can generate parallel coordinate plots in a very simple way: https://plot.ly/python/parallel-coordinates-plot/

Comment: Ahh, thank you! Could not figure out the correct name of the graph.

Comment: I just added an extra answer to the [referred question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60401570/12046409) with example data resembling this question, and with Bézier curves between the axes.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to create 4 extra y axes, and set explicit limits for them. All the y-values can be rescaled to be compatible with the host axis.

(The code can still be optimized to make better use of numpy.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, host = plt.subplots()

N = 20
y1 = np.random.uniform(10, 50, N)
y2 = np.sin(np.random.uniform(0, np.pi, N))
y3 = np.random.binomial(300, 0.9, N)
y4 = np.random.pareto(10, N)
y5 = np.random.uniform(0, 800, N)
ys = [y1, y2, y3, y4, y5]
y0min = ys[0].min()
dy = ys[0].max() - y0min
zs = [ys[0]] + [(y - y.min()) / (y.max() - y.min()) * dy + y0min for y in ys[1:]]
ynames = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5']

axes = [host] + [host.twinx() for i in range(len(ys) - 1)]
for i, (ax, y) in enumerate(zip(axes, ys)):
    ax.set_ylim(y.min(), y.max())
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
    if ax != host:
        ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
        ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')
        ax.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", i / (len(ys) - 1)))

host.set_xlim(0, len(ys) - 1)
host.set_xticks(range(len(ys)))
host.set_xticklabels(ynames)
host.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=7)
host.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

colors = plt.cm.tab20.colors
for j in range(len(ys[0])):
    host.plot(range(len(ys)), [z[j] for z in zs], c=colors[j % len(colors)])

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Yes, this is much better that the way I went with normalizing all the values to 0-1 range. Thanks for the help. Will rewrite my code.